# require client certificates in IIS without requiring SSL

Tags: security, authentication, iis, ssl, certificate

In IIS 7, I've created an https binding for a site, and I'd like to require client certificates for https and still keep my http endpoint.

That is to say, I'd like to require client certificates for my https endpoint without requiring SSL across the board and disallowing access to my http endpoint (via "require SSL" in SSL Settings). Is this possible?

Comment: There is no way for the client to provide a certificate using HTTP (as opposed to HTTPS) using only transport layer security.

Comment: i'd like to require client certificates without requiring SSL across the board (i'd like to keep the http endpoint, but require client certs for https)

Answer (score 1):

Client certs are usually used for 2-way SSL, so not just the server but the client is also encrypting the traffic with it's private key.

If you don't want to enforce https across the board, then the one thing you can try is to accept the client cert ( see SSL settings ) then implement the cert validation in your application.

See Request.ClientCertificate on MSDN for more details

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
// it's SSL, so check the client cert
bool authorized = IsClientCertAuthorized(HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate)
}
```

Then implement that method as needed.

Note: I haven't tested this, so please comment if you've tried.

Comment: thanks for your response. i'm not working in code, i'm using the IIS Manager UI. Is there a way to do this through the ui?

Comment: if someone can turn this into a managed iis module for you then you could add that module to the pipeline and return a 403.7 - Client certificate required if there is no client cert over ssl